# react-native run-androind giving error of 500 on first time

Tags: android, react-native

I just installed react native and created a fresh project, But when I'm running it by using `react-native run-android` command it is giving error. I didn't changed anything in any file the project is just created.

Here are the error and screenshot of it.

[image: screenshot of error]

### Error

The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:

> {"originModulePath":"C:\project\test\App.js","targetModuleName":"./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js","message":"Unable to resolve module './../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js' from 'C:\project\test\App.js': The module './../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js' could not be found from 'C:\project\test\App.js'. Indeed, none of these files exist:\n  * 'C:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)'\n  * 'C:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)'","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module './../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js' from 'C:\project\test\App.js': The module './../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js' could not be found from 'C:\project\test\App.js'. Indeed, none of these files exist:\n  * 'C:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)'\n  * 'C:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)'"}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module './../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js' from 'C:\project\test\App.js': The module './../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js' could not be found from 'C:\project\test\App.js'. Indeed, none of these files exist:\n  * 'C:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)'\n  * 'C:\react-transform-hmr\lib\index.js\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)'\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:209:697)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:222:485)\n    at Object.resolve (C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:149:25)\n    at dependencies.map.result (C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:316:29)\n    at Array.map ()\n    at resolveDependencies (C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:312:16)\n    at C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:169:33\n    at Generator.next ()\n    at step (C:\project\test\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:271:307)"}
>   processBundleResult
>       BundleDownloader.java:296
>   access$200
>       BundleDownloader.java:37
>   onResponse
>       BundleDownloader.java:174
>   execute
>       RealCall.java:153
>   run
>       NamedRunnable.java:32
>   runWorker
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113
>   run
>       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588
>   run
>       Thread.java:818

Please help me get out of this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try these steps:

1- Clear the cache using:

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*;
```

2 - If you are using the watchman, remove all watches and associated triggers with:

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

3 - Restart the Metro Bundler from the project folder

```
react-native start  --reset-cache
```

4 - Run `react-native run-android`

Comment: Thank you Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before try this solutions,

1- Restart metro bundler with `npm start`

2- Restart project with different port `react-native run-android --port=8088`

Because sometimes default port 8081 may used by another app.

Comment: Thanks for helping...:)
But this solution didn't worked for me.